# Array formula to return true across multiple dates combined with if "sepecific text"= true

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, array

I am trying a formula that is sets out dates for a week and lists jobs on each day based on the days they are booked in. the array formula is designed to look up data on my current sheet (cell A1) on a separate sheet based on the date in a specific column.

I have 2 columns determining these dates the first to set the start (first day)
and the second finish date (last day). I also want all dates in between to return first and last day to return true. I also need a third condition to be met which will be if text in another column is the same as the formula dictates "text"

This Formula is intended to be used on a sheet other than sheet one...

BUT!!! its not working :( can someone help me please, maybe its the "AND" function or the order
I have my conditions??

```
{=INDEX(IFERROR(FILTER('SHEET 1'!A:A,(AND(A92>=MIN('SHEET 1'!P:Q),A92<=MAX('SHEET 1'!P:Q)*('SHEET 1'!F:F="TEXT")))),),ROWS(C93:C93))}
```

Comment: Your verbiage is a little confusing.  And the formula does not give sufficient information for us to help. `A92>=MIN('SHEET 1'!P:Q)` would return a single TRUE/FALSE where we would want an array the same size and shape as `'SHEET 1'!A:A`  Please [edit] the post to include a mock table with the necessary data and expected output.

Comment: Something tells me you want: `=FILTER('SHEET 1'!A:A,(A92>='SHEET 1'!P:P)*(A92<='SHEET 1'!Q:Q)*('SHEET 1'!F:F="TEXT"),"")`  You do not need to use Ctrl-Shift-Enter or INDEX, it should spill down automatically.

Comment: sorry about the verbiage, my understanding of the formulas Im working out is pretty limited. 
your suggestion with the filter function has helped. i still needed it to array as its running down a column and needs to be indexed to return multiple values in a list. 

the trouble I'm having now is that I need the filter function to run on 2 text conditions and a date both text conditions are in the same column and what i have worked out doesn't work.  see next comment... character limit...

Comment: This is working... 
{=INDEX(IFERROR(FILTER('TRUSS JOBS AND DELIVERY'!A:A,('SHEET1'!L:L=A3)*('SHEET1!M:M="text1")),),ROWS(C4:C4))}

this isn't working 
{=INDEX(IFERROR(FILTER('TRUSS JOBS AND DELIVERY'!A:A,('SHEET1'!L:L=A3)*('SHEET1!M:M="text1")*('SHEET1!M:M="text2")),),ROWS(C4:C4))}

any ideas why??

Comment: Any ideas how i could get the above second formula to work properly?

Comment: M:M cannot be both text1 and text 2 at the same time you need or not and.  Or is `+`: `(('SHEET1!M:M="text1")+('SHEET1!M:M="text2"))`